# Can I use same folder location of my pc to store 2 different cloud storage's data?

Tags: cloud, data-storage, data-synchronization, cloud-storage

I want to store my same data into 2 different cloud storages to ensure extra safety. Is there any problem during synchronization for random modification from both account?
Cloud storages are : Dropbox and MS One drive.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a destructing work, there are many possibilities of losing your data, because the cloud storage systems are time stamps, they always perform some sync operation to the local folder with cloud, If you delete a file/ folder from the local, that will delete also from the both cloud storage.

[Details about](https://superuser.com/questions/631257/using-the-same-local-folder-for-dropbox-and-skydrive)

Comment: Thank you, I'm concerned about the deletion. Now, consider a scenario: I have changed a file from both of my account. My local file is not updated yet. What will happen if I update my local copy. Will my both changes be merged or lost one or both? There may more other scenario like that.